# one or two digits in regex

Tags: regex

How can I represent approving numbers with one or two digits? for example 08.9 is fine and 8.9 is fine? 
I can't use this [0-9].[0-9]|[0-9]{2}.[0-9] it will complicate other things for me. can I use something that would mean with or without [0-9]?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reword your question? You are asking lots of questions without providing enough information. What kind of data are we looking at? What do you want to match vs what to avoid. You mention '[0-9]' but your example regex uses that group (which could be simplified by '\d') 4 different times.

Comment: What does *approving numbers* mean? What exactly are you trying to match? What are the specifications that decide what does (and does not) match? It's very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can understand your question the following should do what you appear to be asking:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d
```

Comment: Actually, your regex do not use anchors (^ and $), so 'abc12,1def' would match your regex. Look : https://regex101.com/r/iP6bS8/1